# Assembly path in test case

Tags: .net, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm writing a test case where the method under test validates if path exist. The path is located in the folder the assembly is being output. 
So I have the code to get folder path as
string assemblyLocation = typeof(ReportViewer).Assembly.Loaction;

ReportViewer exists in the same assembly. When I run the test case, it ends up picking the path of the folder of the assembly test case is running from.

When I run the app, method under test returns right path but during test case it gives my the path of test assembly. Any clue why?

I'm using MSTest as testing framework.

Comment: I assumed you are using the VS unit testing framework in my answer and in retagging (seems correct from symptoms you described), please correct me if I assumed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what unit testing framework you are using, however, in Visual Studio Professional (and above) built-in tests, tests are executed from test assembly in test result's out directory and all referenced assemblies are copied there.

FYI, if your code depends on any non referenced assemblies (loaded with reflection or unmanaged assemblies) or any other resources that need to be in execution directory, then you will need to copy them there during the tests' class initialize (which is ran before constructor).

This enables flexible configuration of testing environment (e.g. separate app.config file).

Edit - Reply to comment:

The code returns the correct result - execution directory, I assume the reason you are looking for the bin directory is that you have some resources under there. If this is the case, copy them to the tests' out dir before the test starts (in the tests' class's class initialize method).

Comment: I'm using MSTest. Given that MSTest copies all assemblies to the Test assembly directory, how would we come over the issue I'm facing?

Comment: @Sheraz don't forget that on the client's machine, the application can usually be installed anywhere. You have to make sure that everything your application needs is in the installation directory (= execution directory), except for stuff that can be changed, which should be under appdata. The tests' out directory is where the "app" they are testing is "installed".